# Why does archlinux's uname command show like this?

Tags: archlinux, archlinux-arm, linux-distro

When I input `gcc -v`, it just shows the same...

I have try it in Debian and it behaves normally..

[image: I only meet this problem in arch and how can i fix it??]

Comment: What do you mean by `gcc -v` shows the same?  I would find it very unlikely that `gcc -v` shows its target as `unknown` in any working distro.  `gcc` has its target defined at compilation time.

Answer (score 1):

`uname -i` is non-portable according to `man uname` and it can be compiled out.  My new Debian 8 also prints it as

```
$ uname -i
unknown
```

`uname` is part of the [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) and it is a very simple program.  you can see the [code on savannah](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/uname.c;h=962a6cfcb2090a9f22cfeb732310e4a87328c7bf;hb=HEAD).  If you look through the command line option there `--hardware-platform` is `-i`:

```
  88 static struct option const uname_long_options[] =
  89 {
  90   {"all", no_argument, NULL, 'a'},
  ...
  97   {"machine", no_argument, NULL, 'm'},
  98   {"processor", no_argument, NULL, 'p'},
  99   {"hardware-platform", no_argument, NULL, 'i'},
 100   {"operating-system", no_argument, NULL, 'o'},
 101   {GETOPT_HELP_OPTION_DECL},
 102   {GETOPT_VERSION_OPTION_DECL},
 103   {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}
 104 };
```

Which forces the printing of the define `PRINT_HARDWARE_PLATFORM`

```
 198       while ((c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "asnrvmpio",
 199                                uname_long_options, NULL)) != -1)
 200         {
 201           switch (c)
 202             {
 ...
 227             case 'p':
 228               toprint |= PRINT_PROCESSOR;
 229               break;
 230 
 231             case 'i':
 232               toprint |= PRINT_HARDWARE_PLATFORM;
 233               break;
```

Which, in turn does the printing of "unknown" by default.

```
 344   if (toprint & PRINT_HARDWARE_PLATFORM)
 345     {
 346       char const *element = unknown;
 347 #if HAVE_SYSINFO && defined SI_PLATFORM
 348       {
 349         static char hardware_platform[257];
 350         if (0 <= sysinfo (SI_PLATFORM,
 351                           hardware_platform, sizeof hardware_platform))
 352           element = hardware_platform;
 353       }
 354 #endif
```

If i am not mistaken (i might be) `HAVE_SYSINFO` should be in `sys/systeminfo.h`, and that file is not present by default in `arch`.  That does not necessarily mean that it was not there when the package was compiled.  Yet, it shows that, most likely, the packager did not bother compiling the package with `HAVE_SYSINFO` properly setup.  Which is acceptable since it is a non-portable option.

---

See my comment about `gcc -v`, my arch evaluates it correctly to `Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`.  But that has nothing to do with `uname`, `uname` sends system calls to print information about the system, `gcc` has the target compiled into it.

---

Note: saying that `uname` is part of `coreutils` is not 100% correct.  `uname` is part of the POSIX standard, yet the `-i` (`--hardware-platform`) option to `uname` is not part of that specification.  `-i` is only implemented by the `coreutils` package (hell, *BSD systems have `-i` but it has a completely different meaning there).